# List index is out of range from scraping URLs from a search engine

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium to pull links that populate from a search engine. As you can see below, I am appending each list value to a unique key in "cvDict."

The Problem: sometimes these searches do not populate 20 results (i.e. the search queries data that is more rare and cannot feed the query more than 20). I'm sure you know what I'm trying to explain. Just want to make sure I cover all my bases.

What type of statement/function could I write that would keep the error from occurring when the search query results in fewer than 20 results and causing the error?

Do I need to write 20 separate if/elif statements (or something of the sort) ranging from 1 to 20 in increments of one? to make sure that the results satisfy one of them?

```
cv = []
        bbb = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('user-name')
        # while True:
        for plink in bbb:
cv.append(plink.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href'))




    self.cvDict = {'one': cv[1],
                   'two': cv[2],
                   'three': cv[3], 'four': cv[4], 'five': cv[5],
                   'six': cv[6], 'seven': cv[7],
                   'eight': cv[8], 'nine': cv[9], 'ten': cv[10],
                   'eleven': cv[11], 'twelve': cv[12], 'thirteen': cv[13], 'fourteen': cv[14],
                   'fifteen': cv[15], 'sixteen': cv[16], 'seventeen': cv[17], 'eighteen': cv[18],
                   'nineteen': cv[19],
                       }
```

If you're wondering why the spacing is weird it's so I can comment out just one or two of the key value pairs when I'm getting 9 search results and have 10 key value pairs set in the dict (for example) that then raise the error.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you have a list `cv` of unknown length (less than 20) and you want to push it into a dictionary with custom keys

an easy way is to define your keys in a list

```
keys = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

and then zip it together with `cv` and make a dictionary out of it

```
cvDict = dict(zip(keys, cv))
```

length of cv does not have to be as long as `keys`

```
keys = ["one", "two", "three"]
cv = ["something", "something else"]
cvDict = dict(zip(keys, cv))
```

will produce

```
{'one': 'something', 'two': 'something else'}
```

same thing with the keys, if the cv would be longer, it gets shortened to the length of the shorter list

Comment: "zip" may be the keyword here. I'll try it out right away and let you know but I'd be shocked if this didn't do it. Pumped to try it out! I'll let ya know.

Edit: And thank you! haha

Comment: Sure enough. Nailed it. The question was elementary, but just the fact that I'm able to articulate my coding problems in a way that allows people like you to give direct and complete solutions that work is just a great feeling. The hardest part of the learning curve, I think. Thanks, Derte!